# can´t find element on a linked list

Tags: c

I have the next code, first i create a list from a file named hc12,and then i search the codop = "BLE" that has to be found on the list, but instead i keep getting the message COULDNT FIND CODOP. i dont know why, the linked list works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    char *code;
    struct nodo *next;
}COD;

COD *createNodo(char *instruction);
void insertEnd(char *instruction,COD *last);
COD *lastElement(COD *head);
void remove(char *c);
void searchEndofLine(FILE *fd);
void ignoreSpaces(FILE *fd);
void CodopsList(COD *head);
char *OperandsTable(FILE *hc12);
COD *searchCodop(COD *head,char *codop);

int main()
{
    COD *head = NULL,*found;
    char *codop = "BLE";
    CodopsList(head);
    if((found = searchCodop(head,codop)) == NULL)
        printf("COULDNT FIND CODOP");
    else
        printf("CODOP FOUND");

    return 0;
}


void searchEndofLine(FILE *fd)
{
    int car;
    while((car = fgetc(fd))!= '\n')
        ;
}

void ignoreSpaces(FILE *fd)
{
    int car;
    do
    {
        car = fgetc(fd);
    }while(car == '\t' || car == ' ');
}

void remove(char *c)
{
    char *ptr;
    if(((ptr=strchr(c,'\n'))!=NULL)||((ptr=strchr(c,'\t'))!=NULL)||((ptr=strchr(c,' '))!=NULL))
       *ptr = '\0';
}

void CodopsList(COD *head)
{
    int car;
    FILE *hc12;
    char *instruction;
    COD *last;
    if((hc12 = fopen("TABOP.txt","r"))!= NULL)
    {
        while((car = fgetc(hc12))!= EOF)
        {
            if(car != '\t')
            {
                instruction = OperandsTable(hc12);
                if(head == NULL)
                    head = createNodo(instruction);
                else
                {
                    last = lastElement(head);
                    insertEnd(instruction,last);
                }
            }
            else
               searchEndofLine(hc12);
        }
    }
    else
       printf("Error\n");
}

char *OperandsTable(FILE *hc12)
{
    int car,lon = 0,pos;
    char *c;
    fseek(hc12,-1,SEEK_CUR);
    pos = ftell(hc12);
    do
    {
        car = fgetc(hc12);
        lon++;
    }while(car != '\t');
    fseek(hc12,pos,SEEK_SET);
    c = (char*)calloc((lon+1),sizeof(char));
    fgets(c,lon+1,hc12);
    remove(c);
    searchEndofLine(hc12);
    return c;
}

void insertEnd(char *instruction,COD *last)
{
    last->next = createNodo(instruction);
    last->next->next = NULL;
    last = last->next;
}

COD *lastElement(COD *head)
{
    COD *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
       ptr = ptr->next;
    return ptr;
}

COD *createNodo(char *instruction)
{
    COD *x;
    int t;
    t = strlen(instruction);
    x = (COD*)malloc(sizeof(COD));
    x->codigo = (char*)malloc((t+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(x->code,instruction);
    x->next = NULL;
    return x;
}

COD *searchCodop(COD *head,char *codop)
{
    COD *ptr;
    for(ptr = head;ptr != NULL;ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        if(ptr->code == codop)
           return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strcmp` instead of comparing two array pointers.

In `searchCodop` instead of

```
if(ptr->code == codop)
```

do

```
if (!strcmp(ptr->code, codop))
```

Comment: I don't know if there is any other error, but that seems to be one.

Comment: Note, strcmp returns 0 (false) for match, negative or positive for difference. And you seem to have a copy paste error in the strcmp call...

Comment: Yup, thanks @BLUEPIXY . Luckily, I've been out of programming in C/C++ for a long long while.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling pointer as pass by value, instead use call by reference. For this, use pointer to pointer. Like that:

In main change

```
CodopsList(head);
```

with

```
CodopsList(&head);
```

And,

Change function

```
void CodopsList(COD *head)
```

with

```
void CodopsList(COD **head)
```

In function CodopsList use head as *head